# How to remove single quotes from string in the List in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate excel pivot automatically as below.

`table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Manager","Status"],columns=["Product"],values=["Quantity","Price"],
               aggfunc={"Quantity":len,"Price":[np.sum,np.mean]},fill_value=0)`

details on : [reference site](http://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-table-explained.html)

I get this from my program

```
{'sales_qty': ['sum'], 'buyer_cnt': ['count,sum']}
```

But I want

```
{'sales_qty': [sum], 'buyer_cnt': [count,sum]}
```

Sum and count,sum are dynamically allocation.

I will try to this variable

`{'sales_qty': [sum], 'buyer_cnt': [count,sum]}`

to aggfunc

`(ex. aggfunc= {'sales_qty': [sum], 'buyer_cnt': [count,sum]})`

How can I remove single quotes from list string?

my code is here :
 [my code](https://gist.github.com/ultraian/a7c8a38682da4cc0d11c910ef4110e17)

Comment: It would help give you an answer if you share  reproducible code  showing how you constructed the dictionary.

Comment: So count and sum are variables that you have set?

Comment: should it only be displayed without the quotes or should it be replaced with something else?

Comment: I updated my ask, please check again. sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inherently remove the quotes around a Python variable. However, you can pass arguments to a function via `**kwargs`

```
import re
def my_function(**kwargs):
    the_dict = {'sales_qty': ['sum'], 'buyer_cnt': ['count,sum']}
    new_dict = {a:re.split("\W+", b[0]) for a, b in the_dict.items()}
    final_dict = {a:[kwargs[i] for i in b] for a, b in new_dict.items()}

    print(final_dict)

my_function(sum=10, count=12)
```

Output:

```
{'sales_qty': [10], 'buyer_cnt': [12, 10]}
```

Comment: @maestromusica Thanks!

Comment: @Ajax1234 I updated my ask and i need string variable not number ex) my_function(sum='aaa', count='bbb') ---> result is {'sales_qty': ['sum'], 'buyer_cnt': ['count', 'sum']}  --> i want {'sales_qty': [sum], 'buyer_cnt': [count, sum]}

Comment: @maestromusica It's my first time to ask this site, I updated my ask.